# Disable ion auth for front end in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I've been trying to accomplish this for some time but no results.. 
I'm using a ion auth in my codeignitor website.

I want to disable ion auth for front end login, and want it to only work for admin side login. is that possible? if yes then how..

my code:

```
    class Login extends MY_Controller {

        public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        require_once APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';
        }

        public function index(){

            $this->render('login');

        }
}
```

This generates below error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI::$ion_auth

Filename: MX/Controller.php

Line Number: 59

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\moneyclues2\application\third_party\MX\Controller.php
Line: 59
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\moneyclues2\application\core\MY_Controller.php
Line: 126
Function: __get

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\moneyclues2\application\core\MY_Controller.php
Line: 59
Function: _setup

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\moneyclues2\application\controllers\Login.php
Line: 7
Function: __construct

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\moneyclues2\index.php
Line: 316
Function: require_once
```

when I extend CI_controller. I got below error for render method

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Login::render() in D:\xampp\htdocs\moneyclues2\application\controllers\Login.php on line 15
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Login::render()

Filename: controllers/Login.php

Line Number: 15

Backtrace:
```

Comment: get Codeigniter instance: `$this->CI =& get_instance();` in top of constructor

Comment: sorry @Vickel that didn't work for me. showing the same error again.

Answer (score 1):

adding ion_auth library `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','ion_auth');` to `autoload.php` worked for me.

and extended MY_Controller in in place of CI_Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the `Ion_Auth` library! `$this->load->library('ion_auth');`

But if you want it to only be in use for admin-related stuff just make two different `MY` controllers in `core` and have your public and admin controllers extend them. Don't autoload `Ion_Auth` if you only use it in 1/2 of your website.

```
class MY_Public_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // load what you need here
    }

}

class MY_Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // load what you need here
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->library('ion_auth');
    }

}
```

Example admin controller:

```
class Somecontroller extends MY_Admin_Controller {

    public function index() {

    }

}
```